# Entrypoint DllRegisterServer was not found while loading VCRuntime140.dll

Tags: windows, apache, dll, dllregistration

I am using 64 bit windows 10 and downloaded VCRuntime.dll (vcredist_x86) for 32bit, installed and saved it in `C:\Windows\System32`.

Since on running httpd.exe while loading Apache http Server it was showing `VCRuntime.dll file missing`,so I tried to register this dll file by cmd:

command regsvr32 vcruntime.dll

but it shows error as:

```
 "VCRuntime was loaded but entrypoint DllRegisterServer was not found".
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: "I am using 64 bit windows 10 and downloaded VCRuntime.dll (vcredist_x86) for 32bit". Have you tried installing the **64 bit** version?

Comment: yeah i installed 64 bit version too and saved it in C:\Windows\SysWOW64..but it shows the same error

Comment: Issue resolved .Actually file i was using was not updated.updated C++ redistribute file can be found on below link

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145